# Strange behavior of fixed element (100% height) and css3 transform / transition

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using Google Chrome 32 in a Windows Vista PC. I'm currently building a off-canvas menu for a project, using `position:fixed` for setting the layout and css `transform` to show / hide the menu.

Working on that, I faced an strange behavior of the layout. If I open in a narrow window to check the mobile version with the off-canvas menu, everything is fine, the menu is correctly positioned and have 100% `height`, like I want it to have. But, if I resize the window, the menu loses its 100% height, and the element gets the parent height (also using `position: fixed`). Has anyone faced this issue too? If yes, how can I avoid that?

Heres the markup for the menu:

```
<body>
  <header>
  <div class="container">
    <span id="logo">LOGO</span>
    <a href="#" id="mobile-nav">Menu</a>
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu" >
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>      
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;  
}

header, nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
header{
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1024px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
 }

#logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#mobile-nav{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: #cc3300;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav{
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #cc3300;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
}

body.active header
{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-30%);
          transform: translateX(-30%);  
}

#menu{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu a{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#menu a:hover{
  background-color: #ff3300;
}
```

You can [check this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/arubm) that reproduces the behavior. Play with the menu button to open / close the menu first, then open the menu and resize the view to check the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the HTML structure as well as some of your CSS to fix the issue you're seeing. Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ChIsA) of the solution.

I believe the issue had something to do with the `translate` so I changed it to use `position` instead.